# @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-context

I'm upgrading spring form 4.3.3 to 5.2.7 and I'm having this exception:

**Exception:**

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyBean' defined in com.test: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'MyBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**code :**

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public MyBean MyBean(String url,
        String user, String password, String id) {
    return MyBean(url, user, password, id,
            new HashMap<String, String>(),false); 
}
```

> PS 1: I'm using context.getBean with args to init my bean

> PS 2: I'm facing this problem at the startup of the application even though im not using the bean at the startup ( I'm using @Scope("prototype") to init the bean whenever it's called)

> PS 3: I didn't have the problem with spring 4.3.3

Comment: Does Component instead of Bean work? Do you inject MyBean with Autowired?

Comment: thanks for your response actually i cant use **@Component** on a method "**the annotation @Component is disallowed for this location** " and no im not using **@Autowired** anywhere I'm just calling the bean with context.getBean and passing the arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to an open issue with Spring 5.x.x version -

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21498

It talks about the issue which is specific to 5.x.x versions.

> Since Spring 5.0 a @Bean can return null and the effect is to leave
> the bean definition in the registry, but make the value not
> autowirable. However, if there is another bean of the same type that
> is not null, it does not become autowirable. Probably it should? The
> exception from Spring doesn't mention the existence of either bean
> (the null or the not null one)

Try marking the fields as Optional so it should not fail at startup.

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public Optional<MyBean> MyBean(Optional<String> url,
        Optional<String> user, Optional<String> password, Optional<String> id) {
    if(url.isEmpty() && user.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty() && id.isEmpty()) {
     return Optional.empty();
    } 
    return Optional.of(new MyBean(url, user, password, id,
            new HashMap<String, String>(),false)); 
}
```

**Update 1**

I think this is more easier solution. Spring 5.0 added Nullable annotation and probably they added this annotation for this kind of scenario only.

API Documentation Link - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC1_to_5.0.0.RC2/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.RC2/org/springframework/lang/Nullable.html

> A common Spring annotation to declare that the annotated parameter or
> return value could be null under some circumstances.

So all needed would be to mark the parameters and return type as Nullable.

```
  @Bean
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
  public @Nullable MyBean myBean(@Nullable String url,
                                 @Nullable String user, @Nullable String password, @Nullable String id) {
    if(url == null && user == null && password == null && id == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return new MyBean(url, user, password, id,
            new HashMap<String, String>(),false);
  }
```

Comment: thank you for mentioning the open issue in spring 5.*.  Optional<String> will be very useful if I was able to return null if non of the parameters are present ( url , id ...) but as i know i can't return null otherwise i will get another error **Bean instance of type [class org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean] is not a FactoryBean**.

Comment: do you have any suggestions to handle NullBean error ( spring 5.2.7 )?

Comment: @AzizBECHINI Can you please elaborate more on NullBean error. When are you getting this ? Is it at the Server startup ? When you refer to returning null, are you returning null from your myBean method ?

Comment: im having the error at the Server startup because in my code I have to test if the values are present to return  **MyBean(url.get(), user.get(), password.get(), id.get(), new HashMap<String, String>(),false);**  otherwise I have to return null

Comment: Can't you return Optional of MyBean then ? So, the return type of the method will be Optional<MyBean> . Also, instead of returning null, simply return Optional.empty()

Comment: @Aziz I updated the answer with what I suggested above

Comment: thank you for your quick response, Okay so I'm going to test the application with the new changes. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: after doing some tests, first i have no problem at startup , but I had some other problems when using the bean :  the type of bean that I'm going to have is **Optional<MyBean>** and not **MyBean** and whenever I want to init the bean I have to pass parameters as **Optional.of(StringValue)** and not **String** and these breaking changes can cause regressions  in other parts of the code

Comment: @Aziz I updated the answer. Probably using Nullable should work. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately no it's not working I'm having the same kind of exception **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyBean' defined in com.beanpackage: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'MyBean' parameter 0** at the Server Startup

Comment: Hmmm, then I think, Optional is the only option. You could try mixing both Optional and Nullable. I mean marking return type as Nullable and String parameters as Optional. Also, If I am correct you are initializing MyBean with new operator. Why do you need to mark it as a Prototype bean ? Why can't you simply create MyBean object wherever it's needed ?

Comment: Actually, I can't return null even with mixing @Nullable annotation with optional ( as you suggested ) **the same NullBean error** (at the startup), I can't initialize MyBean directly as an object otherwise it will be a breaking change ( I'm working on a project and my task is to upgrade spring from 4.3.3 to 5.2.7 and try to handle the problems **without** causing regression in the existing code).